# If $T,S \in L(V)$, how to prove that if $T$ is not surjective then $TS$ is also not surjective ?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T,S \in L(V)$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, how can I prove that if $T$ is not surjective then $TS$ is also not surjective?

Comment: This work in sets in general. If you take an element not in the image of $T$, can it be in the image of $TS$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Notice that $\mathrm{Im}(TS) \subset \mathrm{Im}(T)$.

**Solution 2:** Because $V$ is finite dimensional, $TS$ and $T$ are surjective iff their determinants are nonzero. But $\det(TS)=\det(T) \cdot \det(S)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have ${\cal R} (TS) \subset {\cal R} T$. Hence if $v \notin {\cal R} T$ for some $v \in V$, then $v \notin {\cal R} (TS)$.